# How to convert sql query to cakephp query and use in controller

Tags: cakephp

```
SELECT count(*) FROM payments WHERE status='Success' and createddate BETWEEN '2020-05-05' AND '2020-05-06'

$numcount= TableRegistry::get('Payments')->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('status'=>'Success','and' => array(
    array('createddate <= ' => $date1,
        'createddate >= ' => $date2
    )
))))->count();
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.
I tried but the code doesn't work.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Is your `createddate` field just a date, or does it have the time in it too?

Comment: if i execute this query showing zero always. and `createddate` have `date` only

Comment: `$date1` is which date?

Comment: yes $date1='2020-05-05' and $date2='2020-05-06' eg. `SELECT count(*) FROM payments WHERE status='Success' and createddate BETWEEN $date1 AND $date2`

Comment: So, "between 2020-05-05 and 2020-05-06" means "greater than or equal to 2020-05-05 and less than or equal to 2020-05-06". You've got them the other way around. There's no date less than or equal to the 5th and also greater than or equal to the 6th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your dates backwards. Also, you don't need an extra 'AND' in your conditions, they're all AND by default.

```
$numcount= TableRegistry::get('Payments')->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'status' => 'Success',
        'createddate >=' => $date1,
        'createddate <=' => $date2
    )
))->count();
```